# same name .h and .c file and the revocation relation ship among these file?

Tags: c

I am new about this field.
I am trying to read one sample program.

The first is `team.c`

```
#include "support.h"

struct team_t team = {
  "", /* first member name
  "", /* first member email
  "", /* second member name
  ""  /* second member email
};
```

It include `support.h`, which is:

```
#ifndef SUPPORT_H__
#define SUPPORT_H__

/*
 * Store information about the team who completed the assignment, to
 * simplify the grading process.  This is just a declaration.  The definition
 * is in team.c.
 */
extern struct team_t {
  char *name1;
  char *email1;
  char *name2;
  char *email2;
} team;

/*
 * This function verifies that the team name is filled out
 */
void check_team(char *);

#endif // SUPPORT_H__
```

The `check_team` function is in the `support.c`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "support.h"

/*
 * Make sure that the student names and email fields are not empty.
 */
void check_team(char * progname) {
    if ((strcmp("", team.name1) == 0) || (strcmp("", team.email1) == 0)) {
        printf("%s: Please fill in the team struct in team.c\n",
               progname);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Student 1 : %s\n", team.name1);
    printf("Email 1   : %s\n", team.email1);
    printf("Student 2 : %s\n", team.name2);
    printf("Email 2   : %s\n", team.email2);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Finally, in the part1a.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "support.h"
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        check_team(argv[0]);
        /*some other code*/
        return 0;
    }
```

After I use makefile to generate target file. when I run `. some forlder/part1a` in terminal, it works well, to output content of `team`

I have two confusing points. 1. I feel confused about the definition of team, whose value given in `team.c` but defined in `support.h` and `extern` used to get again, what's the order when program running? 2. support.h and support.c have same name, if they have any other relationship?

Comment: These are basic C questions better answered by reading a C book or tutorial. Or do a search as these basic concepts are dealt with many times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.h is commonly used for header files. Header files are normally used to declare things such as classes/structs and functions without implementing them. In this case, team.h is declaring the team struct and check_team function while support.c is defining check_team. The compiler knows how to put these different pieces together. Also while support.h and support.c do share a name, that is not why they have a relationship, but merely a convention. Typically you would have some header file like team.h that you could include in all files that need it and then implement it elsewhere. But naming conventions do not force relationships.